# Dell Inspiron mini laptop - access Bios blind?

Tags: bios, passwords, external-display, dell-inspiron

I picked up a Dell laptop Inspiron 1018 mini at a school fund raising sale cheap.  Screen is cracked so it only works on external screen which is OK, but here is the kicker... we also don't have password to access Windows 7 (Starter Edition) login screen.

A mate passed me microsoft program on a USB stick which I am supposed to is supposed to be able to override password or re-install drive. (he was not sure)

Now the problem... It seems that can't boot from the USB without changing to boot from USB.  I should be able to get to this screen by pressing F8 or F12 however computer does not shift over to external monitor screen until I get to Microsoft login screen. Hence I can't get to BIOS screen.

Question:
Can someone provide detailed instructions to navigate this BIOS blind?
Better solution?

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut to go to external screen (Fn+F?). You may be able to enter the BIOS (obviously you won't know) then switch to external display.

Comment: Any progress reports? This would be a useful topic to solve, or not, for other users.